# Inserting my own illegal characters into Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() in C#

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

How can I extend the `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars` to include my own set of characters that is illegal in my application?

```
string invalid = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
```

If I wanted to add the '&' as an illegal character, could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify an existing function, but you can write a wrapper function that returns `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` *and* your illegal characters.

```
public static string GetInvalidFileNameChars() {
    return Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Concat(MY_INVALID_FILENAME_CHARS);
}
```

Comment: The following seems to work: new String('&', 1) but I don't get what int occurs means? "The number of times char occurs"?

Comment: The string constructor which takes a char and int allows you to create a string consisting of a char repeated a specified number of times.  For example, `new String('x', 5)` gives "xxxxx"

Answer (score 15):

```
typeof(Path).GetField("InvalidFileNameChars", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, new[] { 'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', '9', '0', '0', '0' });
```

Comment: +1 for being clever, however I would blow a gasket if I ever found something like this in production code :)

Comment: I can't believe people voted this up. Not that it isn't clever -- it is; but if I saw a programmer doing this in production code I'd curse loudly, submit his work to the Daily WTF, and run. Quickly.

Comment: The people who voted this up did so largely because they have a sense of humor. Of course, in Ruby, the same would be much more widely accepted - largely because language support (vs framework support seen here) for such meta programming. Of course, this wasn't a Ruby question, but even if you don't see value in learning how and why this is ok in a different world, it at least suggests Reflection (which none of the answers did), which is a good thing to be familiar with (if for no other reason than to know that this isn't a good use for it).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var invalid = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Concat(new [] { '&' });
```

This will yeild an `IEnumerable<char>` with all invalid characters, including yours.

Here is a full example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // This is the sequence of characters
        var invalid = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Concat(new[] { '&' });
        // If you want them as an array you can do this
        var invalid2 = invalid.ToArray();
        // If you want them as a string you can do this
        var invalid3 = new string(invalid.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you incorporate into this: string invalid = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars())

Answer (score 1):

An extension method is your best bet here.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static char[] GetApplicationInvalidChars(this char[] input)
    {
        //Your list of invalid characters goes below.
        var invalidChars = new [] { '%', '#', 't' };
        return String.Concat(input, invalidChars).ToCharArray();
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

`string invalid = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().GetApplicationInvalidChars();`

It will concatenate your invalid characters to what's already in there.

Answer (score 0):

First create a helper class "SanitizeFileName.cs"

```
public class SanitizeFileName
{
   public static string ReplaceInvalidFileNameChars(string fileName, char? replacement = null)
   {
      if (fileName != null && fileName.Length != 0)
      {
         var sb = new StringBuilder();
         var badChars = new[] { ',', ' ', '^', '°' };
         var inValidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Concat(badChars).ToList();

         foreach (var @char in fileName)
         {
            if (inValidChars.Contains(@char))
            {
               if (replacement.HasValue)
               {
                  sb.Append(replacement.Value);
               }
               continue;
            }
            sb.Append(@char);
         }
         return sb.ToString();
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
var validFileName = SanitizeFileName.ReplaceInvalidFileNameChars(filename, '_');
```

in my case, i had to clean up the "filename" on the "Content-Deposition" in Response Headers in a c# download method.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + validFileName);
```